# ggplot donut chart has visible sectors instead of solid colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm seeing these visible white lines that denote how many objects are in each count. How can these be removed? They aren't present in when I am using geom_bar alone but become apparent with coord_polar.

I think the issue may have something to do with using stat identity or position fill, but I need that because my facets are of different size and to get the percentage labels to show up at the correct location.

[image]

Data:

```
    zz <- "variable set value   group_size  value_size  pos
1   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
2   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
3   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
4   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
5   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
6   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
7   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
8   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
9   efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
10  efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
11  efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
12  efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
13  efficiency.category four_week   GREEN   44  13  6.5
14  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
15  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
16  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
17  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
18  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
19  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
20  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
21  efficiency.category total   GREEN   44  8   4.0
22  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
23  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
24  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
25  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
26  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
27  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
28  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
29  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
30  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
31  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
32  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
33  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
34  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
35  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
36  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
37  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
38  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
39  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
40  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
41  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
42  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
43  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
44  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
45  efficiency.category four_week   YELLOW  44  24  25.0
46  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
47  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
48  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
49  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
50  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
51  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
52  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
53  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
54  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
55  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
56  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
57  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
58  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
59  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
60  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
61  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
62  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
63  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
64  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
65  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
66  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
67  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
68  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
69  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
70  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
71  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
72  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
73  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
74  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
75  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
76  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
77  efficiency.category total   YELLOW  44  32  24.0
78  efficiency.category four_week   RED 44  5   39.5
79  efficiency.category four_week   RED 44  5   39.5
80  efficiency.category four_week   RED 44  5   39.5
81  efficiency.category four_week   RED 44  5   39.5
82  efficiency.category four_week   RED 44  5   39.5
83  efficiency.category total   RED 44  3   41.5
84  efficiency.category total   RED 44  3   41.5
85  efficiency.category total   RED 44  3   41.5
86  efficiency.category four_week   GRAY    44  2   43.0
87  efficiency.category four_week   GRAY    44  2   43.0
88  efficiency.category total   GRAY    44  1   43.5"

data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Code to produce graph:

```
efficiency.graph <- ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(variable),
                                     y=value_size[1]/group_size[1], fill=value)) + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
      theme(axis.text=element_blank()) +
      theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") + 
      coord_polar(theta="y", direction=-1) + 
      geom_bar(width=0.4, stat="identity", position="fill") +     
      facet_grid(~set) +
      geom_text(aes(y = pos/group_size, 
                    label = paste(round(100*value_size/group_size), '%', sep=''),
                    size=8))

print(efficiency.graph)
```

Comment: Do you get the white lines running this exact data/code (your linked plot looks like it is based on slightly different code)?  I can't reproduce the white lines using ggplot2_2.1.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: You can reproduce it if you look at a vector output, like svg or pdf. That's because the every donut is contructed by those sectors.